# Change axes ticks of quiver - Python

Tags: python, vector, matplotlib

I'm plotting a vector field with the **quiver** method of **Matplotlib**.

My array to store this vector has a dimension **x * y** but I'm working with a space that varies from **-2** to **2**.

So far, to plot the vector field I have this method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_quiver(vector_field_x, vector_field_y, file_path):
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplots()
    plt.quiver(vector_field_x, vector_field_y)
    plt.savefig(file_path + '.png')
    plt.close()
```

Which gives me this output, as an example, for a **10 x 10** array:

[image]

But to generate this vector field I centered my data in the **x = 0**, **y = 0**, x and y ranging from **-2** to **2**.
Then, I would like to plot the axis of the image following this pattern.

As an standard approach, I tried to do the following:

```
def plot_quiver(vector_field_x, vector_field_y, file_path):
    plt.figure()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.quiver(vector_field_x, vector_field_y)
    ax.set_xticks([-2, 0, 2])
    ax.set_yticks([-2, 0, 2])    
    plt.savefig(file_path + '.png')
    plt.close()
```

Which usually works with **Matplotlib** methods, as **imshow** and **streamplot**, for example.

But this what I've got with this code:

[image]

Which is not what I want.

So, I'm wondering how can I perform what I explained here to change the axes ticks.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny thing, I just learnt about `quiver` yesterday... :)

According to the [quiver documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=quiver#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver), the function can accept from 2 to 5 arguments...

The simplest way to use the function is to pass it two arrays with equal number of elements `U` and `V`. Then, matplotlib will plot an arrow for each element in the arrays. Specifically, for each element `i,j` you will get an arrow **placed at `i,j`** and with components defined by `U[i,j]` and `V[i,j]`. *This is what is happening to you*

A more complete syntax is to pass our arrays with equal number of elements `X`, `Y`, `U` and `V`. Again, you will get an arrow for each `i,j` element with components defined by `U[i,j]` and `V[i,j]`, but this time **they will be placed at coordinates `X[i,j]`, `Y[i,j]`**.

#### In conclusion:

you need to call `quiver` like

```
quiver(values_x, values_y, vector_field_x, vector_field_y)
```

Probably you already did it, but you can get `values_x` and `values_y` using the [`numpy.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) function.

The [matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/quiver_demo.html) for the `quiver` function might be useful, also.

I hope it helps!

Comment: As we do with the __streamplot__... Thank you. (: